# Optimize Multiple Joins with multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle, join

EXPLAIN: I'm running this SQL that takes >6 hours to run and I'm trying to see if this SQL code (please see  below) could be made better. I realize that there are multiple joins from various tables, so it is a bit cumbersome. It should be noted that there are ~2 million rows. Any suggestions are much appreciated. THANKS!!!!

PLAN: Should I deconstruct this SQL into multiple tables and then union it all together? OR Is there a better approach? Sorry, I'm a bit lost in how to approach this problem b/c I was recently informed that I need to run this SQL everyday with only 1 thread.

```
select /*+ ordered full(t) full(s) full(l) full(b) parallel(72)*/
                 t.column1
                ,b.column1 
                ,to_date(t.column2,'YYYYMMDD') 
                ,to_date(b.column2,'YYYYMMDD')
                ,cr.column1 
                ,cr.column2 
                ,s.column1
                ,t.column3
                ,t.column4
                ,b.column4 as paid_clm_unique_key
                ,CASE WHEN t.column5 IN ('ASTR','HIHI','HITR','HOTR','PHTR') THEN 'YES'
                WHEN t.column5 IN ('HIOI','HOHE','HOHO','HOHS','HOOO','HOOS') THEN 'NOPE'
                   ELSE 'MAYBE' END type_cd
                ,t.column6
                ,m.column6 
                ,last_day(to_date(t.column7,'YYYYMMDD'))          
                ,last_day(to_date(t.column8,'YYYYMMDD')) 
                ,S.column8
                ,case when substr(S.column8,1,4) = '0999' then 'PREPAY' else 'OTHER' END REASON_CD
                ,S.column9
                ,' 'column10
                ,case when t.column9 = 'EM' then substr(l.column1,1,3) else substr(l.column1,3,5) end code1
                ,case when t.column9 = 'EM' then substr(l.column6,1,3) else substr(l.column6,3,5) end code2
                ,t.column10
                ,nvl(t.column11,'NVAL') 
                ,t.column12
                ,t.column13 
                ,t.column14
                ,t.column15
                ,nvl(t.column16,'NVAL') 
                ,t.column7
                ,t.column17 
                ,cr2.column17 
                ,nvl(b.column17,0) 
                ,nvl(b.column18,0) 
                ,case when b.column1 is null then t.column17
                      when sum(b.column17) over (partition by t.column1) = 0 then (t.column17/count(b.column1) over (partition by t.column1))
                      else (b.column17/sum(b.column17) over (partition by t.column1)) * t.column17 end as d_amt_wdup
                ,t.column17/(case when sum(t.column17) over (partition by b.column1) = 0 then count(t.column1) over (partition by b.column1)
                                  else sum(t.column17) over (partition by b.column1) end) * nvl(b.column17,0) as p_amt_wdup
                ,t.column17/(case when sum(t.column17) over (partition by b.column1) = 0 then count(t.column1) over (partition by b.column1)
                                  else sum(t.column17) over (partition by b.column1) end) * nvl(b.column18,0) as p_n_amt_wdup                    
                ,case when row_number() over (partition by t.column10,nvl(t.column11,'NVAL'),t.column14
                                                           ,t.column15,nvl(t.column16,'NVAL'),t.column17,b.column1
                                              order by t.column7 desc,t.column1 desc) = 1 then 'N' else 'Y' end as duplicate  
               from TABLE1 t
                join TABLE2 m on t.column20 = m.column20
                join TABLE3 cr on m.column6 = cr.column20
                join TABLE4 s on t.column1 = s.column20       
                join TABLE5 l on t.column1 = l.column20
                left join TABLE1 b on b.column2 >= to_char(add_months(last_day(trunc(sysdate)),-13),'YYYYMMDD') --rolling 13 mos.
                        and b.column20  in ('EM','LV')
                        and t.column10 = b.column21
                        and nvl(t.column11,'NVAL') = nvl(b.column22,'NVAL')
                        and t.column15 = b.column23
                        and t.column3 = b.column24    
                        and t.column14 = b.column25 
                        and nvl(t.column16,'NVAL') = nvl(b.column26,'NVAL')
                        and t.column27 < nvl(b.column27,'99990101')   ---paid at least 1 day after rejected
                        and t.column7 <= nvl(t.column28,'99990101') --makes sure paid not received before rejected 
                        and t.column2 <= nvl(b.column2,'99990101') --paid mth after/equal to rejected mth
                        and nvl(b.column2,'99990101') >= nvl(b.column29,'00010101') --filter out future CCCC month
                        and b.column30 = 'C'  
                        and b.column17 <> 0 
                left join TABLE2 m2 on b.column31 = m2.column31
                left join TABLE3  cr2 on m2.column32= cr2.column32                        
                where t.column2 >= to_char(add_months(last_day(trunc(sysdate)),-13),'YYYYMMDD') --rolling 13 mos.
                and s.column40 >= to_char(add_months(last_day(trunc(sysdate)),-13),'YYYYMMDD') --rolling 13 mos.
                and l.column40 >= to_char(add_months(last_day(trunc(sysdate)),-13),'YYYYMMDD')  -- rolling 13 mos.
                and t.column9 in ('EM','LV') and s.column50 in ('EM','LV') and l.column50 in ('EM','LV')
                and t.column17 <> 0     
                and s.column60 not in ('Y','S','D') 
                and t.column60 = 'R'
                      
                group by t.column61
                ,b.column1
                ,t.column17
                ,t.column62
                ,b.column17
                ,b.column18
                ,t.column3
                ,to_date(t.column2,'YYYYMMDD')
                ,to_date(b.column2,'YYYYMMDD')
                ,t.column2
                ,cr.column1 
                ,cr.column62
                ,s.column1
                ,t.column4
                ,CASE WHEN t.column5 IN ('ASTR','HIHI','HITR','HOTR','PHTR') THEN 'YES'
                WHEN t.column5 IN ('HIOI','HOHE','HOHO','HOHS','HOOO','HOOS') THEN 'NOPE'
                   ELSE 'MAYBE' END
                ,t.column63
                ,m.column6
                ,t.column12
                ,t.column13 
                ,cr2.column17
                ,last_day(to_date(t.column7,'YYYYMMDD'))          
                ,last_day(to_date(t.column8,'YYYYMMDD'))  
                ,S.column8
                ,case when substr(S.column8,1,4) = '0999' then 'PREPAY' else 'OTHER' END 
                ,S.column9
                ,case when t.column9 = 'EM' then substr(l.column1,1,3) else substr(l.column1,3,5) end 
                ,case when t.column9 = 'EM' then substr(l.column6,1,3) else substr(l.column6,3,5) end
                ,t.column10
                ,nvl(t.column11,'NVAL')
                ,t.column14
                ,t.column15
                ,nvl(t.column16,'NVAL')
                ,t.column7
                ,b.column4
```

Comment: Is this `~2 million rows` in the results? If so, you might need to reduce the number of columns used in the GROUP BY (if possible).  This is because all result needs to be know before grouping can be done, resulting in a large temporary result.

Comment: Please add the EXPLAIN PLAN for this query to your question

Comment: notably, it depend on the frequency of calling of this procedure. we have solutions for different scenarios. highly frequent , frequent , low frequent

Comment: Hi A Farmandbar, I was recently informed that I need to run this SQL on a daily basis, which was the reason for posting this question.

Comment: Hi Luuk, good point. I guess the group by items aren't necessary.

Comment: This looks like Oracle. I'll add the tag for you.

Comment: You will need to get a SQL Monitor report, so that you can see where time is being spent

Comment: "`parallel(72)`"? Do you really have 72 free cores to run this query? There's no point in specifying a high DOP if your server doesn't have the resources.

Comment: Tuning Oracle queries requires a lot of details about the specific case. Please read [this thread on asking such questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34975420/146325). This will show you how to improve your question; it will also give you some insight into how you can investigate the problem for yourself.